# How do I play as Black Goku in DBZ Xenoverse 2?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I pre-ordered the game and I don't have Black Goku or the 'to pi' thing (sorry if I spelled that wrong).

I don't know if I get that stuff later in the game or it's supposed to be there in the beginning of the game. What is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the game I bought didn't come with the pre order bonus. I thought I got the Day One Edition which was the preorder.

Comment: @Vemonus / RudolfL.Jelínek - This is actually Gavin's answer. He apparently bought the wrong version

Comment: @Robotnik my bad, not sure how I missed that